# One to many relationship with Fixed values in many side

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, one-to-many

I have requirement where I have warehouse and warehouse can have products from 5 fixed categories (More than one at a time e.g wh1 can have producttype1 and producttype2 products). what should be a suggested database design. one option is to create fixed values' separate table and make many to many relationship with warehouse. what could be other option
**Warehouse Table**

```
WareHouseID, WareHouseTitle,Address
```

**Fixed product types**

```
Producttype1,Producttype2,Producttype3,Producttype4,Producttype5
```

Comment: Never would you want to allow for 5 possible categories because in the real world things change. You don't want to go back and redesign because tomorrow someone introduces a 6th. Definitely a many-to-many requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I think you already answered your own question:

> warehouse can have products from 5 fixed categories (More than one at a time >e.g wh1 can have producttype1 and producttype2 products)

The only proper design would be WAREHOUSE_TABLE 1-* M2M_TABLE *-1 PRODUCT_TYPE_TABLE as anything else will break 3NF rules.